# How to iterate a collection between two items?

Tags: c#, list, loops, linq

Consider for example a List of objects:

```
List<MyClass> myList;
```

I have a method which passes two references to items within the list. I want to iterate all items within the given ones (note: I don't know which of the two items comes first within the list):

```
privat void MyFunction(MyClass listItem, MyClass anotherListItem)
{
    foreach(var item in ????)
    {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Currently I have solved this usecase as follows:

```
int listItemIdx = myList.IndexOf(listItem);
int anotherListItemIdx = myList.IndexOf(anotherListItem);

if(listItemIdx < anotherListItemIdx )
{
    for(int i = listItemIdx ; i <= anotherListItemIdx ; i++)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i = anotherListItemIdx ; i < listItemIdx ; i++)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant, efficient or built-in solution to this problem?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay op is looking for range of items, some sort of combination of SkipWhile/TakeWhile

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ah yes, I misread the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for *performance* (`IndexOf` twice can be a bit slow) and *generalization*
(when `myList` is not necessary `List<T>` but `IEnumerable<T>` only) you can put it as

```
bool proceed = false;
MyClass lastItem = default; 

foreach (var item in myList) {
  if (!proceed) {
    if (proceed = item == listItem) 
      lastItem = anotherListItem; 
    else if (proceed = item == anotherListItem) 
      lastItem = listItem; 
  }

  if (proceed) {
    //TODO: do staff here

    if (item == lastItem)
      break; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, won't work for `IEnumerable<T>` because we can't do `==` on `T` if `T` is not constrained to be a reference type.

Comment: @E. Shcherbo: in *general case* we can use `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation (or even `IComparer<T>` implementation) to compare `item`, `lastItem` and `anotherListItem`. Note, please, that in general case `myList.IndexOf(anotherListItem);` without comparer (OP's solution) is incorrect as well, that's the main reason I skipped comparer in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You iterate three times over the list: Two times in `IndexOf`, and then once again in your loop. You can make your code more efficient with this code, which iterates only once over the list.

```
privat void MyFunction(MyClass listItem, MyClass anotherListItem)
{
    bool betweenTwoItems = false;
    foreach(var item in myList)
    {
        if(item == listItem || item == anotherListItem)
        {
            betweenTwoItems = !betweenTwoItems;
            if(!betweenTwoItems)
            {
               break;
            }
        }

        if(betweenTwoItems )
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

We set a bool variable if we are between the two items. In the beginning, it is false. The we iterate over the list and check whether the current item is one of the two method parameters. If this is the case, we invert the value of the bool. If after the inversion of the bool the value is false, we can leave the list. After that, we check whether the bool is true. If so, we can do stuff.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xYcr7V

Comment: Yap, the additional iterations of `IndexOf` are what bothers me. Your solution is definitely more efficient. It surprises me, that there is no built-in (=optimized) linq function for this use-case, as I thought this might be relatively common.

Comment: I'll leave the question open for a bit longer, but mark this answer if no other comes along as it is the only one so far which improves performance.

Comment: There's a problem if `listItem` appears *twice*, e.g. `{listItem, listItem, item1, item2, anotherListItem}`: note, that we'll have a `break` on the *second* `listItem`

Answer (score 1):

More generic version of the same idea. So this can be created as extension method for `IEnumerable<,>`

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RangeOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, T el1, T el2, 
  IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
  comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
  var hasStarted = false;
  var end = default;
        
  foreach (T el in elements)
  {
    if (!hasStarted) 
    {
      hasStarted = comparer.Equals(el, el1) || comparer.Equals(el, el2);
      end = comparer.Equals(el, el1) ? el2 : el1;
    }
            
    if (hasStarted)
      yield return el;
            
    if (comparer.Equals(el, end))
      yield break;
  }
}
```

and version with the `while` loop supporting ranges from `el` to `el`. For example for `[5, 0, 1, 2, 0, 6]` the range `[0, 0]` will be `[0, 1, 2, 0]`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RangeOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, T el1, T el2,
  IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{   
  comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
  var hasStarted = false;
  var end = default;
        
  var it = elements.GetEnumerator();
  while (!hasStarted && it.MoveNext())
  {
    T el = it.Current;
    hasStarted = comparer.Equals(el , el1) || comparer.Equals(el , el2);
    end = comparer.Equals(it.Current, el1) ? el2 : el1;
  }
        
  if (hasStarted)
    yield return it.Current;
        
  while (it.MoveNext())
  {
    yield return it.Current;

    if (comparer.Equals(it.Current, end))
      yield break;
  }
}
```

both can be used like this

```
foreach (var el in list.RangeOf(listItem, anotherListItem))
  // Do with el whatever you want to do
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the list sorted? The you can use that fact to realize which item must be first. Nevertheless you can do with one for-loop, if you prefer:

```
private static void MyFunction(string item1, string item2)
{
    List<string> input = new() {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

    int index1 = input.IndexOf(item1);
    int index2 = input.IndexOf(item2);
    int beginIndex = Math.Min(index1, index2);
    int count = Math.Abs(index1 - index2) + 1;

    foreach (string item in input.GetRange(beginIndex, count))
    {
        Console.Write(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing solution can be improved:

```cs
int listItemIdx = myList.IndexOf(listItem);
int anotherListItemIdx = myList.IndexOf(anotherListItem);
int startIdx = Math.Min(listItemIdx, anotherListItemIdx);
int endIdx = Math.Max(listItemIdx, anotherListItemIdx);

for(int i = startIdx ; i <= endIdx ; i++)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Thus, the code duplication disappears and only a minor refactoring is required.

To create a range-loop version, you can create a subset using [GetRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange), something like:

```cs
int listItemIdx = myList.IndexOf(listItem);
int anotherListItemIdx = myList.IndexOf(anotherListItem);
int startIdx = Math.Min(listItemIdx, anotherListItemIdx);
int endIdx = Math.Max(listItemIdx, anotherListItemIdx);
var subset = myList.GetRange(startIdx, endIdx - startIdx);

foreach(var item in subset)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Thus, filtering the list and processing the list can now be separated.